# Using more than one friendly url with Mod_Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I was able to get the urls to work using this code

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1/index.shtml?dynContent=$2 [L]
```

So dynContent = apples or bananas or bananas-apples

So if I type in http://example.com/dir1/apples or /dir1/bananas or /dir1/bananas-apples it displays using the correct content I am pulling into index.shtml

However I have one page that needs to be full page with and I have one page configured to go full page and it is named as indexFP.shtml

The dynContent=oranges for this one page

I have the RewriteRule as

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1/indexFP.shtml?dynContent=$2 [L]
```

But this does not call up the correct page with full page for this one page.....

When I type in http://example.com/dir1/oranges it uses index.shtml instead of indexFP.shtml

Is there a way to do this?  Here is what I have now.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1/index.shtml?dynContent=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1/indexFP.shtml?dynContent=$2 [L]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[L]` means "last" in mod_rewrite. That stops processing so your `indexFP` rule above will never get hit.

What I think you are trying to do is choose `index` for some strings and `indexFP` for others. To do that you need a way to choose one rule over the other. My rewrite-fu is a little rusty but something like:

```
# match "oranges"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /oranges/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1/indexFP.shtml?dynContent=$2 [L]

# match everything else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1/index.shtml?dynContent=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Wow...that works!  Is there a way to make this more dynamic?  I was just thinking that this is specific for oranges....suppose it was apples?  Just trying to figure a way it can do this without having to enter each one in here and having to restart apache each time.

Comment: I think I was able to figure it out...from your example.

# match "oranges"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)FP/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1/indexFP.shtml?dynContent=$2 [L]

# match everything else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1/index.shtml?dynContent=$2 [L]

Comment: For dynamic lookups use RewriteMap. It reloads the map file automatically when the file is modified so you don't have to reload Apache. RewriteMap would also let you use a single ruleset rather than the "if-else" construct above.

Comment: Do you have a good reference I can look at?  Or a good tutorial you can recommend?

Comment: The main Apache docs describe the directives pretty well. There is a link to what they call the "detailed" docs that includes a fair number of use cases and examples. See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/

Edit: also I've found that turning on the rewrite debug log is extremely helpful to see the various phases of rewrite and to verify that your rules are (or are not) being run. The debug log is very verbose at high levels so only use it in testing. I think I used level 5 but YMMV.